# JavaScript fullCalendar plugin reading 'applyAll' as undefined in gcal.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am attempting to use the google calendar module of the fullcalendar plugin in JavaScript. When I attempt to load the google calendar, the console is displaying:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'applyAll' of undefined
```

The error is occurring on line 23 of gcal.js:

```
21| var fc = $.fullCalendar;
22| console.log($.fullCalendar);
23| var applyAll = fc.applyAll;
```

The console.log() that I have added returns $.fullCalendar as undefined, and then fc.applyAll is also returning undefined. My knowledge of JS is not good enough to fully understand what is going on in this file, and I am not sure what is going wrong.

Here is my html:

```html
<head>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
  <script src='fullcalendar/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='fullcalendar/gcal.js'></script>
  <script src='fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
  <script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
  <link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' />
</head>
<body>
  <div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
```

My JavaScript:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        googleCalendarApiKey: 'my-api-key',
        events: {
          googleCalendarId: 'my-calendar-id'
        }
      });
    });
```

And I have downloaded the most recent version of gcal.js (there seemed to be a problem with the file, and the site provided a link to the most up to date version).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is with the order you've imported the library files.

fullcalendar is a jQuery plugin, which usually means it will end up as a property on the jQuery object e.g. `$.fullCalendar`.

Now, the gcal file depends on that property being there, so that it can access the `.applyAll` method on it, however, you're loading `gcal.js` before you load `fullcalendar.js`.

If you change the ordering like this, it works without problems.

```
<script src='fullcalendar/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/gcal.js'></script>
```

As a rule of thumb, try and put the files that you know have no dependencies (they don't rely on another library) first.